# UI created from code won't show up

Tags: user-interface, swift, ios8

I'm trying to create a user interface from code. This is the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let superview = self.view

        let myLabel = UILabel()
        myLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        myLabel.text = "My Label"

        let myButton = UIButton()
        myButton.setTitle("My Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        myButton.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        superview.addSubview(myLabel)
        superview.addSubview(myButton)

        var myConstraint=NSLayoutConstraint(item: myLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: superview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        superview.addConstraint(myConstraint)

        myConstraint=NSLayoutConstraint(item: myLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: myButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        superview.addConstraint(myConstraint)

        myConstraint=NSLayoutConstraint(item: myButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: myLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -10)
        superview.addConstraint(myConstraint)

        myConstraint=NSLayoutConstraint(item: myButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Baseline, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: myLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Baseline, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        superview.addConstraint(myConstraint)

    }
```

According to the book tutorial I'm following, this code should create a Button and a Label. When I run the simulator nothing shows up(blank simulator). Can you help me find the error(s)?

Comment: When you run that code, a huge long error message appears in the console, starting with "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints...". It completely explains the problem. Read it! It's telling you exactly what the error is. Do not ignore console messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third constraint

```
myConstraint=NSLayoutConstraint(item: myButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: myLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -10)
```

Tries to put the label and button side by side.

Your second constraint

```
myConstraint=NSLayoutConstraint(item: myLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: myButton, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
```

Tries to put them one above the other.

One of these two constraints is going to have to go!